# Error You do not have sufficient permission to transfer/cancel this participant

Tags: civievent, registration

If "Allow self-service cancellation or transfer" is enabled on an event, there is a link to the event self-service page contained in the registration confirmation email. When a user clicks on this link, they receive the following message on our site:

"Error You do not have sufficient permission to transfer/cancel this participant."

My questions: Is there a permission which allows anonymous users following the link to self-service the registration? Or is this functionality only available to logged-in users?

Answer (score 2):

Jason, Welcome to stackexchange. Sorry for the problem you facing. There is no specific permission required to cancel your registration and neither the user should be logged in. However the url should have correct parameter i.e contact checksum. eg

```
http://www.domain.org/civicrm/event/selfsvcupdate?reset=1&pid=53&cs=7f51ab615c6bdcb785d1947e122b1c14_1548964126_inf
```

If the cs is invalid then you will get above error. So please check if the url is correct and hopefully not encoded.

HTH

Pradeep

Comment: The self-service works in some situations, but not all. I created a new event and registered. The link to the self service worked. I went to a previously created event, deleted my registration and re-registered. Again the self service link worked. I then went to an old registration email from a previously created event. The link worked if I was logged in as admin, but it gave me the insufficient permission error if I tried it as an anonymous users. Here is the link: `http://outdoorstewardship.org/civicrm/event/selfsvcupdate?reset=1&pid=239&cs=ef37dd69efc3ddc6df08cac1e656a660_1544806649_168`

Comment: Its missing '_inf' '